# UNION Operatior OWB properties

Tags: oracle-warehouse-builder

i am a newbie in OWB Dataware house builder , i wanted to know about the SET operator union Function , the union function is it UNION or UNION ALL ?

simple union means remove full duplicates while UNION ALL means All rows .

Answer (score 1):

You can set the operation in the properties editor, if the SET operator is selected.

Possible operations are:

- UNION
- UNIONALL
- MINUS
- INTERSECT